# print regular dictionary with list values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `my_d` dictionary that you see below:

```
my_d={'Names':['Kate','Clair','Jack'],'Ages':['21','31','38'],'Cities':['New York','Amsterdam','Oslo']}
```

I want to have an output in this way:

```
Kate  is  21 from  New York.
Clair is  31 from  Amsterdam.
Jack  is  38 from  Oslo.
```

I noticed there is a problem in regular dictionary that doesn't have order. This is not a good solution for me because the order changes again. I tried to order by value or key:

```
for key, value in sorted(l.items(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k)):
    print "%s: %s" % (key, value)
```

Still not the one that I want. 
I even used order `collections.OrderedDict()` by both key and value:

```
print collections.OrderedDict(sorted(l.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]))
```

but as you see the output is not in order:

```
OrderedDict([('Ages', ['21', '31', '38']), ('Cities', ['New York', 'Amsterdam', 'Oslo']), ('Names', ['Kate', 'Clair', 'Jack'])])
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Dictionary order (which, btw, is fixed in the latest versions of Python, 3.6+) doesn't appear to have any relevance. You're storing _lists_ against keys and they _do_ maintain order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that your dictionary has those specific keys, then you can use `zip()`, as follows:

```
for l in zip(my_d['Names'], my_d['Ages'], my_d['Cities']):
    print("{:5s} is  {} from  {}.".format(*l))
```

Out:

```
Kate  is  21 from  New York.
Clair is  31 from  Amsterdam.
Jack  is  38 from  Oslo.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
my_d={'Names':['Kate','Clair','Jack', 'Josh'],'Ages':['21','31','38', '31'],
      'Cities':['New York','Amsterdam','Oslo', 'Manchester']}

for i, name in enumerate(my_d['Names']):
    print("{} is {} and from {}".format(name, my_d['Ages'][i], 
          my_d['Cities'][i]))
```

I have a feeling that your data structure is not correct for this information, though. With more context, we may be able to suggest something better. The issue is not dictionary ordering, per se, since the order of the "headers" (dictionary keys) is irrelevant; the order of your data *is* preserved in the lists stored against the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your example, the information you want to print are stored in lists, which are *ordered*, so you can just print them normally with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
my_d = {
    "Names": ["Kate", "Clair", "Jack"],
    "Ages": ["21", "31", "38"],
    "Cities": ["New York", "Amsterdam", "Oslo"],
}

for name, age, city in zip(my_d['Names'], my_d['Ages'], my_d['Cities']):
     print('%s is %s from %s' % (name, age, city))

# Kate is 21 from New York
# Clair is 31 from Amsterdam
# Jack is 38 from Oslo
```

However, if you were to store the data in just a nested dictionary, such as:

```
my_d = {
    "Kate": {"age": 21, "city": "New York"},
    "Clair": {"age": 31, "city": "Amsterdam"},
    "Jack": {"age": 38, "city": "Oslo"},
}
```

You would need to be concerned about order here, since only *unordered* dictionaries exist. You would need to sort the dictionary `items()` by their respective ages and apply [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

sorted_by_age = OrderedDict(sorted(my_d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["age"]))
for name, info in sorted_by_age.items():
    print("%s is %s from %s" % (name, info["age"], info["city"]))

# Kate is 21 from New York
# Clair is 31 from Amsterdam
# Jack is 38 from Oslo
```

**Note:** You can avoid being concerned about dictionary order if you upgrade to **Python 3.6+**, since insertion order is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas` is straight-forward. Just iterate through the rows of your `DataFrame` as follows

```
import pandas as pd

my_d = {'Names':['Kate','Clair','Jack'],'Ages':['21','31','38'],'Cities':['New York','Amsterdam','Oslo']}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_d)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  s = row['Names'] + ' is ' + row ['Ages'] + ' from ' + row['Cities'] + '.'
  print(s)
```

Output

```
Kate is 21 from New York
Clair is 31 from Amsterdam
Jack is 38 from Oslo
```